# Get root config files path inside dll

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows

I have a (website|windows) app and a dll(classlibrary). i want to get the root(website|windows) config file path in the dll.

I tried ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration with different assembly.get's but they always giving the dll config path.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi found this and it works well

```
 Configuration config;

        if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current != null &&
            System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.PhysicalPath.Equals(String.Empty) == false)
        {
            config = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration(HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppVirtualPath);
        }
        else
        {
            config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
        }
```

Basicly it will get web.config if its a website and it will get app.exe.config if its a windows app